# Apply two separated background images to table body

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply two separated background images to a table body like this:

[image]

Limiting the horizontal stripes to the columns 1 through 3 and the vertical stripes to column 4.
Column 4 has a fixed width. The widths of column 1 through 3 is responsive.

I don't seem to find a way to limit the length of either background image via background size.
See [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ec8bfs9u/4/).
How do I accomplish this?

```
tbody {
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #f8f8f7 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(#f8f8f7 50%, transparent 50%);
background-position: right top, left top;
background-size: 40px 100%, 100% 80px;
```

}

Comment: don't forget background-repeat:no-repeat;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal stripes seem to alternate between table rows so we can use nth-child(odd)/(even) to get a grey/white background respectively.

The length of the stripes can be controlled by creating them as linear gradients from the right since we know the width of the last column. That width is set to be transparent and the rest to the gray or white.

The vertical stripes can be created using linear gradients of fixed width and repeating them. If we put that background on tbody it will get overwritten on all but the last column by the horizontal stripes so giving the desired result.

This snippet declares a CSS variable with the value of the width of the last column and uses CSS calc to calculate the widths of the vertical stripes.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  --col4W: 350px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0ef;
}

tbody {
  --w: calc(var(--col4W) / 15);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to left, #eeeeee 0, #eeeeee var(--w), transparent var(--w), transparent calc(2 * var(--w)));
}

th, td {
  border-left: 1px solid #f0f0ef;
}

th {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

td {
    height: 38px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, transparent var(--col4W), white var(--col4W), white 100%);
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, transparent var(--col4W), #eeeeee var(--col4W), #eeeeee 100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td style="width: 300px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```